# Running Apache ANT on macOS 13.5.2 Homebrew (MBP M1)

Tags: deployment, ant

I am trying run Apache ANT tool for deploying packages from partial to production.
Once I try and run ANT tool in terminal, this error pops out:

```
override Ant's normal entry point/bin/ant: File name too long
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/ant
```

I was trying a lot of things, from aliasing to moving the actual exec file, but nothing actually works.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  ant for Salesforce use.  Is there a reason you can't use the current [Salesforce command line interface (CLI)](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/salesforcecli)